# Python TKinter Treeview selection : IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

kinda new in python and tkinter. I am having difficulties with treeview table. I created a table. and the data inside of it came from mysql database. now whenever I use this syntax of :

x = userid_tree.selection()[0]

I got thin (IndexError: tuple index out of range) and so i cannot run the code and i cannot select whatever row inside the treeview table.

thank you in advance for those who will help.

this is my code.

```
userid_tree = ttk.Treeview(self)
        userid_tree['show']='headings'
        #Define table columns
        userid_tree["columns"] = ("un","pw","cpw")
        #Assign width, minwidth and anchor to the respective columns
        userid_tree.column("un", width=90, minwidth=50, anchor= CENTER)
        userid_tree.column("pw", width=90, minwidth=50, anchor= CENTER)
        userid_tree.column("cpw", width=90, minwidth=50, anchor= CENTER)
        #Assign the heading names to the respective columns
        userid_tree.heading("un", text="Username", anchor= CENTER)
        userid_tree.heading("pw", text="Password", anchor= CENTER)
        userid_tree.heading("cpw", text="Verify PW", anchor= CENTER)
        
        #function to run table
        
        i = 0
        conn1 = mydb.cursor()
        #Select from table name in DB
        conn1.execute("SELECT * FROM user_data")
    
        
        # x = userid_tree.selection()[0]
        # print(x)
        
        for ro in conn1:
            userid_tree.insert('', i, text='', values=(ro[0], ro[1], ro[2]))
            i = i+1
        
       
        userid_tree.place(x=275, y=50)

        x = userid_tree.selection()[0]
        print(x)
```

Comment: The treeview is just created, why do you expect there is item selected?

Comment: there are data already inserted in the treeview with the syntax "for ro in conn1"

Comment: Yes there are data but no item is selected.

Comment: oh i see.. my objective is, whatever the user selected on the table it will be deleted with a delete button. I placed that code x = userid_tree.selection()[0] in a function and the delete button will call it. But whenever I do that, it won't run the program instead it displays above error =(